# How to reference a 3rd party jar in my jar eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, jar

I'm creating a plugin for my android app, this is my first attempt. I want to use org.eclipse.jdt.core-X.X.X.jar in my jar.But I'm facing this error:-

```
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   AndroidJavaException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.messages_en_IN', key ''
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr obj, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Call (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at TestScript.CallTheFunction () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
06-30 11:30:27.930: I/Unity(13847):   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I placed both my jar and org.eclipse.jdt.core-x.x.x.jar in Plugins\Android folder of unity. According to the error I need to add org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar in classpath but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you mean is adding a library into your project, this can be easily done if you right click on your project and go to "Java Build Path" and then to the Libraries tab, click on "Add External JARs" and select your jar file.

I'd recommend you to have that JAR inside your project folder.

Also check this out: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F

> Open the context menu on the project, and select Properties > Java
>   Build Path > Libraries. From here, you can add JAR files to the build
>   path, whether they are inside your workspace or not. You can also add
>   a class folder, a directory containing Java class files that are not
>   in a JAR. Note that plug-in development has more restrictions on where
>   build path entries can come from. For plug-in projects, you should
>   always let the plug-in development tools organize your build path for
>   you. Simply select the plugin.xml file, and choose PDE Tools > Update
>   Classpath from the context menu.

**Also, don't forget to do an import when you are using it.**

Comment: @RaviKumar Check the link that I've posted on my "answer".

Comment: Are you importing the library when you are using it?

Comment: I put org.eclipse.jdt.core-x.x.x.jar inside libs folder my android Library project and export it as a jar but still same issue.